# Multiple Stereo AudioTracks

Tags: android, audio

I am using two Audiotracks set to stereo, one for the right channel and one for the left. While they both work great by themselves, when I try and play them both at the same time I either lose a channel or one of the channels is choppy. They are both started in an AsyncTask.

How can I get both of them to play together?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following stackoverflow questions:

- [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454296/androidplaying-audiotrack-multiple-times-producing-crash)
- [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425526/android-mixing-multiple-audiotrack-instances)

Comment: Both of these are similar, but not the same as my current question. The first link is about ensuring that the AudioTrack instance is cleared. In the second link problem was solved by using separate threads, which mine do. Regardless, thanks for contributing.